# using java for replacing text in database

Tags: java, mysql

i am using replace method for editing text in mysql database and its working well for

every time i try to replace a string by some other string e.g

```
    REPLACE(Eligibility_Points , '(ii)', 'second point is')";
```

works well for above case

but does not work well in the following case

```
    REPLACE(Eligibility_Points , '(ii)-(iii)', 'second and third point is')";
```

how should i fix this problem, thanks for your help

Comment: Sorry if this is trivial, but the second line won't work as expected after the first one executed.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that this is the MySQL `REPLACE` string function you are talking about, the only reason I can see why the second example wouldn't work is that (maybe) the `Eligibility_Points` field (or whatever) doesn't contain the first string at all.

Maybe you could provide more context; e.g. what evidence you have that the replace isn't working.

However @vadchen makes a good point.  If you do the replacement in the first example, then it will remove all examples that might trigger a replacement in the second example.  Maybe you just need to do the "edits" in the reverse order.

---

There is no need to escape any of the characters in those fragments, either from the Java or SQL perspective.

Comment: My question is not related with this question